# What does the hash (#) value associated with the ARM LDR instruction mean?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to debug a crash I am experiencing in my application. The stack trace is pointing to an LDR instruction with the following format (thanks disassembler):

```
LDR R3, [R0,#4]
```

My question is in regards to the source component. What does the #4 in the second parameter mean? I'm assuming it is some kind of offset, but I haven't found documentation supporting that for the LDR instruction.

Comment: In general in arm assembler the # is used to indicate an immediate value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It loads R3 from the address in R0 + 4 bytes. So, yes, it is a byte offset. [See this explanation of the addressing modes](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/addressing.html).

Comment: For a really comprehensive coverage, always wise to read [ARM Assembly Language by Pete Cockerell](http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/html/frames.html) [(PDF)](http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/resources/pdf/all.pdf) - a good book, quite old, but still possibly the best ARM learning aid.

Answer (score 2):

It adds 4 to the value in R0 and uses that as the address to load a 32 bit value into the register R3

Answer (score 2):

**In GNU gas, the hash `#` is only required for ARMv7 when not using `.syntax unified`**

For example, you can write it without `#` for ARMv8 `aarch64-linux-gnu-as`:

```
LDR x0, [x0,4]
```

or if use `.syntax unified` in `arm-linux-gnueabihf-as`:

```
.syntax unified
LDR x0, [x0,4]
```

More details at: [Is the hash required for immediate values in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652884/is-the-hash-required-for-immediate-values-in-arm-assembly/51987780#51987780)