# How to write .syntax unified UAL ARMv7 inline assembly in GCC?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, armv7

I want to write unified assembly to get rid of pesky `#` in front of my literals as mentioned at: [Is the hash required for immediate values in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652884/is-the-hash-required-for-immediate-values-in-arm-assembly/51987780#51987780)

This is a minimal non-unified code with `#`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t io = 0;
    __asm__ (
        "add %0, %0, #1;"
        : "+r" (io)
        :
        :
    );
    assert(io == 1);
}
```

which compiles and later runs fine under QEMU:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -ggdb3 -march=armv7-a -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra \
  -fno-pie -no-pie -marm -o 'tmp.o' 'tmp.c'
```

If I try to remove the `#`, then the code fails with:

```
/tmp/user/20321/ccoBzpSK.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/user/20321/ccoBzpSK.s:51: Error: shift expression expected -- `add r3,r3,1'
```

as expected, since non-unified seems to be the default.

How to make that work?

I found the promising option:

```
gcc -masm-syntax-unified
```

but adding it did not help.

If I write instead:

```
".syntax unified; add %0, %0, #1;"
```

then it works, but I would have to do that for every `__asm__` which is not practical.

UI also found that without `-marm`, then it does use unified assembly, but it generates thumb code, which I don't want.

Maybe this bug is the root cause of the problem: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88648

Tested in arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 5.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's a longshot, but: Sometimes later options in a command line can overwrite earlier options.  Where did you put the `-masm-syntax-unified`?  Also, if you did add the `.syntax unified` thing, presumably you'd have to put it back when you were done.  Seems like you could wrap the string in a macro, but that'd be at least as ugly as using `#1`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thanks, I should have tried that earlier. Apparently it's an incompatibility with `-marm`, which might be a GCC bug. Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Devs replied again soon to the issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88648#c3 and a patch was committed at: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/2fd2b9b8425f9fc4ad98d48a0ca41b921dd75bd9 (post 8.2.0) fixing `-masm-syntax-unified`. Awesome!