# What Does # Mean in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, 68000

For example, what would be the difference between, MOVE 8,D2 and MOVE #8,D2? Just wondering what the # represents and what would happen without it.

Comment: It's the prefix for an immediate value.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097958/what-does-the-hash-value-associated-with-the-arm-ldr-instruction-mean

Comment: @Sigma The linked question is on ARM, this one on m68k - How can this be a duplicate? ARM uses # on offsets as well, m68k doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GNU AS, if you use the # before anything else on a given line, the line will be ignored (comment).  If use # before a value after an instruction, the value will be considered an immediate.  If you want to use in-line comments at that point on the same line, you have to use C-style (i.e., /* comment here */) comments.  For example:

```
# Write the palette to CRAM
lea Palette, a0                 /* Move palette address to a0 */
move.w #size_palette_w-1, d0    /* Loop counter = 8 words in palette */
```

Answer (score 5):

in 68k assembly, the # sign denotes immediate constants. Everything else is normally considered an address:

```
move.w #6,d0
```

will load the constant immediate value 6 into register d0, while

```
move.w 6,d0
```

will do something entirely different: It will fetch the word at the constant address 6 into register d0

Answer (score 1):

Means the following is a number instead of a register.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can also write `move #foo, d2` using a symbol `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in ARM and OP's code means an immediate constant but in other assembler types this symbol is different for example # is the same as $ in x86.